# AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id' in non-eager execution mode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to set up a simple minimisation procedure. I'm perplexed as to why I'm getting a

```sh
AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id'
```

when I run the following code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def minimize_error():
    with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()):
        param = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(param)
        opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
        opt_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[param])

print(tf.executing_eagerly())
# False
print(tf.__version__)
# 1.14.0
minimize_error()
```

In [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250679/refvariable-object-has-no-attribute-id), I read the error means it wants me to be in Eager Execution mode. I don't want to be in that mode, and why is this happening?

EDIT: I now realise that the reason is because I was using `tf.keras.optimisers.*` instead of `tf.train.*`. I'll leave the question open, in case someone wants to answer as to why this happens under the hood.

Comment: 'tf.enable_eager_execution()' solves the problem fro me.