# Neural Style Transfer, using Python and iteration error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, iteration

I am studying the Neural Style Transfer tutorial, and am new to this subject, the paper is available [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576.pdf) and am following the exact code available [here](https://keras.io/examples/generative/neural_style_transfer/).

I fixed some issues by installing what I needed, TensorFlow environment, etc., but as it comes to the iteration part, the last lines of this example code, an error explodes on the screen which I don't understand why I am seeing it.

Please find the whole code from [GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/generative/neural_style_transfer.py)

This is the iteration part:

```
iterations = 4000
for i in range(1, iterations + 1):
    loss, grads = compute_loss_and_grads(combination_image, base_image, style_reference_image)
    optimizer.apply_gradients([(grads, combination_image)])
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print("Iteration %d: loss=%.2f" % (i, loss))
        img = deprocess_image(combination_image.numpy())
        fname = result_prefix + "_at_iteration_%d.png" % i
        keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(fname, img)
```

And below, is the big error I received after running the iterations.
It would be greatly appreciated if you can advise me on how I can fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\sohei\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2748\3038039193.py", line 4, in <module>
combination_image, base_image, style_reference_image

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 414, in __call__
self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 357, in _initialize
*args, **kwds))

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1349, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1652, in _maybe_define_function
graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1545, in _create_graph_function
capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 715, in func_graph_from_py_func
func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_functi## Heading ##on.py", line 307, in wrapped_fn
return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 705, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(type(e))

AttributeError: in converted code:
relative to C:\Users\sohei:

AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2748\3231027975.py:171 compute_loss_and_grads *
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, combination_image)
anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\backprop.py:980 gradient
    unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\imperative_grad.py:76 imperative_grad
    compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))

AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id'



2022-02-08 12:17:34.494127: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 461, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "C:\Users\sohei\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 450, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Error in message handler

TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression*emphasized text*
```

Comment: Your actual error seems to be this one: `AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id'`. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250679/refvariable-object-has-no-attribute-id) help?

Comment: @aaossa : Thank you very much for your comment! Actually, that solved the problem and helped a lot! 

This is my laptop's processor: 
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz   2.30 GHz
and for only 200 iterations it took ~ 55 minutes!!! 

Any recommendation is greatly appreciated!

#NeuralStyleTransfer #TensorFlow

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['RefVariable' object has no attribute '\_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57250679/refvariable-object-has-no-attribute-id)

Answer (score 0):

This `'AttributeError: 'RefVariable' object has no attribute '_id''` shows when you try to run the code using `TF 1.x` .

I tried replicating the same in `Google Colab` with `Tensorflow 2.7` and it does not show any error.

Try using`Tensorflow 2.x`(eager mode) to run this code (as paraphrased by aaossa) and also run the code using `gpu` which may take less time to execute comparatively.